# Use named instances for other instances

Tags: typeclass, idris, formal-verification, named-instance, semigroup

I'm trying to make a `Semigroup` and `VerifiedSemigroup` instance on *my custom `Bool` datatype* both on operator `&&` and operator `||`:

```
%case data Lógico = Cierto | Falso

(&&) : Lógico -> Lógico -> Lógico
(&&) Cierto Cierto = Cierto
(&&) _ _ = Falso

(||) : Lógico -> Lógico -> Lógico
(||) Falso Falso = Falso
(||) _ _ = Cierto
```

So I first make a *named instance* for `Semigroup` over the  `&&` operator:

```
-- Todos
instance [TodosSemigroup] Semigroup Lógico where
    (<+>) a b = a && b
```

But when making the `VerifiedSemigroup` instance, how do I tell Idris to use the `TodosSemigroup` instance of `Lógico`?

```
instance [TodosVerifiedSemigroup] VerifiedSemigroup Lógico where
    semigroupOpIsAssociative l c r = ?vsemigroupTodos
```

That code gives me the following error:

> When elaborating type of `Prelude.Algebra.Main.TodosVerifiedSemigroup`, method `semigroupOpIsAssociative`:
>   Can't resolve type class `Semigroup Lógico`

Comment: @dfeuer, I think that the problem is that is not implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a newly introduced mechanism for this with the `using` keyword:

```
%case data Lógico = Cierto | Falso

(&&) : Lógico -> Lógico -> Lógico
(&&) Cierto Cierto = Cierto
(&&) _ _ = Falso

(||) : Lógico -> Lógico -> Lógico
(||) Falso Falso = Falso
(||) _ _ = Cierto

instance [TodosSemigroup] Semigroup Lógico where
    (<+>) a b = a && b

instance [TodosVerifiedSemigroup] VerifiedSemigroup Lógico using TodosSemigroup where
    semigroupOpIsAssociative l c r = ?vsemigroupTodos
```

Answer (score 2):

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/issues/1118) at the idris-dev repository. Edwin Brady states that

> Currently (by design) named instances can only be used to resolve a class by being named explicitly, even if there is no normal instance.

So here we have Idris trying to resolve the unnamed `Semigroup Lógico` instance, which is needed in order to define a `VerifiedSemigroup Lógico` instance.

We need some way to specify, in the instance declaration, that a named instance should be used to satisfy a class constraint. I do not know whether this is possible. Quoting Edwin from the linked issue:

> this behaviour isn't documented anywhere

Comment: Well, yes, I know that's the problem. What I need to know is how I can tell the instance of VerifiedSemigroup to use the previously defined Semigroup instance.